# Is $H/L$ isomorphic to $K^*\times K^*$ where $K^*=(K_{\ne0},\cdot)$ with $K$ field and $H, L$ certain subgroups of $GL(2,K)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Let $K$ be a field, $H=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}:a,b,d\in K, ad\ne0\right\}$, $L=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}:b\in K\right\}.$

I'm asked to prove that $H/L$ is isomorphic to $K^*\times K^*$, where "$K^*=(K_{\ne0},\cdot)$". Now, this means I should find a bijective $f:H/L\to K^*\times K^*$ such that $f(AB)=f(A)\cdot f(B)$ - my first doubt is that the operator "$\cdot$" is associated with the sole $K_{\ne0}$ rather than $K_{\ne0}\times K_{\ne0}$. Now, given that $H/L$ is isomorphic to $U=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\[]0&d\end{bmatrix}:a,d\in K, a\ne d, ad\ne0\right\}$, am I correct in saying that $f:\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\[]0&d\end{bmatrix}\mapsto(a,d)$ does the job because $$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}a_1&0\\[]0&d_1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_2&0\\[]0&d_2\end{bmatrix}\right)=f\left(\begin{bmatrix}a_1a_2&0\\[]0&d_1d_2\end{bmatrix}\right)=(a_1a_2,d_1d_2)=(a_1,d_1)\cdot(a_2,d_2)$$? I also have another concern: it seems to me that the $a\ne d$ bit in $U$ makes the cardinality of $U$ shift from that of $K_{\ne0}\times K_{\ne0}$ (at least if $K$ is finite), so I guess it shouldn't be there? But why?

Comment: > my first doubt is that the operator "$\cdot$" is associated with the sole K≠0 rather than $K_{\neq 0}\times K_{\neq 0}$.

$\cdot$ here denotes a generic group operation (in particular, the one on $K^*\times K^*$ induced by the one on $K^*$). 

Where did you get $a \neq d$ from? It's not anywhere else in the question, and makes $U$ not a group (it's missing the identity).

Comment: @user3482749 Ok so I was thinking of $\cdot$ correctly; as for $a\ne d$, how stupid of me, I should have seen that... I somehow thought $a\ne d$ stemmed from the observation that the multiples of elements of $L$ - but now that I think of it, this would make the identity matrix equal to $0$, which isn't possible. Could you please give some hint? I'm so confused